# JavaScript , setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html

I have to create an input type text form on my webpage to modify a `setTimeout` value based on user input in my javascript code while its running. Can i do that and if i can how can i?

I tired to send a String to my backend from user input and than with ajax calls assign the String to a variable in javascript but it does not work because of the inner html is a String , and when i converted it to an int it does not work also.

```
function getData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("idovalt").innerHTML =
       this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "toltes", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Here is an input form:

`var idovalt = 1000;`

`setTimeout(function(){ize()}, idovalt);`

Comment: And the question is why exactly tagged as `c++`?

Comment: Why is this question even upvoted? Title is meaningless; question includes many grammar mistakes; it's unclear ... At first glance, this seems like a simple question (timeout, event handling is very straightforward), but when I start reading it, I realize that the question isn't clear. I ignore questions like this when I see them ... My two cents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strring or integer is irrelevant to the matter.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="idovalt" value="1000">
```

JS:

```
function ize() {
  // do something
}

setTimeout(ize, document.getElementById('idovalt').value);
```

If you want to write some code directly to the first argument of setTimeout(), the code should be quoted.

e.g.,

```
setTimeout('alert("Hello!")', 1000);
```

Comment: `If you want to write some code directly to the first argument of setTimeout(), the code should be quoted.` that is a very bad idea, since the code is being passed through `eval`. At the very, very least it makes it hard to parse as code and as such it makes refactoring harder. This can also hamper other tools that work on the source code. It's better to just make a function in-place as a callback `setTimeout(() => alert("Hello!"), 1000);` now, for example, if you have the `no-alert` rule set in ESLint, it would be triggered.

Comment: Of course I know that and not intended to recommend that way,
The original posted code was written in this style but the syntax was wrong.
So I just pointed it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes can approach this, i going to use Jquery for event handling, but of course may change it.

```
var myInput = $("#timeoutDelay"),
    timeOut = null;


function setTimeOutOnInputChange(timeout) {
    timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Your code...");
        //Ize();
    }, timeout);
}

// I did not get why you are doing this, asynchronous call execute after the timeout function, thats why you need to wait until is ready to change de timeout, in case time out value comes from server and not for user input, otherwise it doesn't makes sense.
function getData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("idovalt").innerHTML = this.responseText;
       setTimeOutOnInputChange(parseInt(this.responseText)); // Assuming does not return an object
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "toltes", true);
  xhttp.send();
} 


myInput.change(function () {
    var val = this.value;
    if (timeOut != null) {
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
    }

    if (isNaN(val)) {
        console.error("Input is not a number");
    } else {
        setTimeOutOnInputChange(val);
    }    
});
```